# How can I display my original product images instead of the ones generated by woocomerce?

Tags: woocommerce

how can I display my original product images instead of the ones generated by woocommerce?
(My products images are much much smaller in size, but the ones generated by woocommerce are almost the double in size)

So in the products shop page I would like to use the original ones instead, as well as in the main page, category page, search page, and the rest of the pages.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your query but this is not advisable to use the Full-size image in all the places as it will make a huge impact in Performance.

Refer the below link which explains about the Hooks which can be used for changing the Image size of Woocommerce products.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/

The below code will change the image size to Full for Shop Page, Sub Category Page, Single Gallery Thumbnail and Single Gallery Main Image.

```
function rf_product_thumbnail_size( $size ) {
    global $product;

    $size = 'full';
    return $size;
}
add_filter( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'subcategory_archive_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
```

Comment: Hello Rajeev, thanks for your kind reply, I added your code at the beginning of the funcions.php file but it didn´t work, where do I need to put it? Thank you so much

Comment: Can you share the website URL?

Comment: Install, this plugin and Regenerate thumbnails and then check.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Since you re using a premium theme, Its better to ask for help in theme support.

Comment: Thank you for your  kind efforts Rajeev, but unfortunately the premium support didn't help and sent me to woocommerce because woocommerce regenerates the thumbnails. I also tried the plugin to regenerates and didn't work either, thanks anyways

Comment: I'm using 2023 child theme and the above code worked for me except for the Newest Products block. Is there a separate hook for the images shown in this block?

Comment: Make sure you are regenerating the thumbnails after you change the size. To regenerate thumbnails, use the "Regenerate Thumbnails" plugin.