# Remove product image cropping from Newest Products blocks in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using latest version of WordPress 6.1.1 and I'm using child of 2023 theme. I've installed WooCommerce. On my home page I'm showing WooCommerce's "Newest Products" block. In this block I'm not able to stop thumbnail image cropping.

I've tried this solution [How can I display my original product images instead of the ones generated by woocomerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628380/how-can-i-display-my-original-product-images-instead-of-the-ones-generated-by-wo)
It works for all thumbnail images but doesn't work for WooCommerce's "Newest Products" block.

I've added all 6 filters mentioned on https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-2

How to fix it?
Is there any separate filter for the images shown in this block?

Here is my code in child's theme function.php

```
function rf_product_thumbnail_size( $size ) {
    global $product;

    $size = 'full';
    return $size;
}
add_filter( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'subcategory_archive_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', 'rf_product_thumbnail_size' );
```